# mod_rewrite root URLs for players AND website pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have player names working from the root directory something.com/username I also have an ID working to load a profile form ID instead something.com/id/1234, But I also want to be able to load my pages from index.php?page=about from something.com/about There are only about 6-10 pages, so I could create these manually in the htaccess.
I also need my search page to work with parameters something.com/search/searchterms

This is my current htaccess file.

```
# BEGIN Pretty Url's
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#Rewrite all urls to use slash at the end.
#RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ ./$1/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([_A-Z0-9a-z-+\.]+)/?$ ./pages/player.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^id/([_0-9-+\.]+)/?$ ./pages/player.php?id=$1 [L]
# END Pretty Url's

# BEGIN Security Features
# Deny config.php
<files config.php>
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
</files>

# Deny all .hta* files
<files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
  satisfy all
</files>

# Deny access to version file
<files inc/version.php>
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
  satisfy all
</files>

# Deny access to security file
<files inc/security.php>
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
  satisfy all
</files>
# END Security Features
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Just add them all above the rules you already have:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(about|page1|page2|etc)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([_A-Z0-9a-z-+\.]+)/?$ ./pages/player.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^id/([_0-9-+\.]+)/?$ ./pages/player.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Assuming the list of pages that you have is "about", "page1", "page2", and "etc". Note that doing something like this means you have have player names that are the same as your page names.

Comment: So simple! Thank you very much, as a side note to anyone else that may find this, I added /? before the $ so that people can use /about and /about/ with a trailing slash.

But one question still about my search page, since I will need to pass search parameters into /search/somethingsearched